# Installing MFC (vs2005) application on Windows 2008 R2 64

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I've build an application that runs on Windows 2003, it is an old style MFC application. Today I need to install the application on a Windows 2008 R2 64 system. I have failures during installation and the application does not run.

The application is build with VisualStudio2005, and uses COM objects. The MSI register the objects but it fails with the error code : HRESULT -2147010895.

Any idea why the COM registration failed?

I've tried to install the "Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable Package (x86)" but it doesn't help. 
I've tried to register the COM objects with the regsvr32 after the installation but sadly it doesn't help. 
I've tries to install the application on Windows 2008 R2 32, and it works perfectly.

I am quite new with 64 systems, so any help will be appreciated.

tia
olich

Answer (score 0):

This topic is more releate to stackoverflow.com questions but as I found the solution I'll share it here. 
The application was developed initially for Windows NT and the defines WINVER and _WIN32_WINDOWS were set to 0x0400 (Windows NT). To fix this issue, I've 'simply' change the two defines to Windows XP (0x0501), built it and that's all.

This is quite magic for me since I don't understand the mechanism, but as long as it works.

hope it helps.
olich